# Getting the post ID outside the loop WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the function `get_the_ID()` to get the ID of current post in WordPress. My understanding was that the loop in WordPress starts with `have_posts()` based on the documentaton (https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action#Begin_The_Loop).

However, I was able to get the correct post ID even before the call to `have_posts()`. Shouldn't I have gotten `false`?

I tried it on `single.php` and well as a specific `page-specific.php` file.

What is considered outside the loop in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

wordpress functions relies on global variable `$wp_query` and `$post`

if you look at [have_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/#source) function, you see it simply calls the `have_posts()` methods of global `$wp_query`

if you look at the [get_the_ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/#source) function, you see it calls another function [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/#source) which again calls the global `$post` variable if you don't provide any parameter.

As long as the global `$wp_query` and `$post` variable is present in where you call, it will always work.

the loop is just another helper to determine if global `$wp_query` and `$post` is present

you can also still use the wordpress helper function anywhere as long as you are calling and hooking it properly

i.e.

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    echo get_the_ID();
});
```

using the code above, the ID will be displayed in wp_head as long as the page you are viewing has post object, so if you visit your 404 page, you wont get any ID, and so, you better properly add a condition that it should only execute if there is a post object

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    if ( is_single() ) // or is_page()  or is_singular()
        echo get_the_ID();
});
```

Comment: Thanks silvar. So, is there any file where I won't get the ID using `get_the_ID()` but will get it with `get_queried_object_id()`? I tried calling `get_the_ID()` in the `functions.php` file and it still worked.

Comment: depends, if you use `get_the_ID` in a proper hook inside functions.php it would still works.